# Runtime error 424 in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset

Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table1", 2)
Set rst2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table2", 2)

Dim strName As String

If Not (rst1.EOF And rst1.BOF) Then
    rst1.MoveFirst
    Do Until rst1.EOF
        rst1.Edit

        strName = rst1![Name]
        rst2.FindFirst ("[Name] = '" & strName & "'")

        If rst2.NoMatch Then
            If rst1![Accepted] Is Not Null Then 'here is the line causing error
                ... 'more code going on
```

So, above is an excerpt from my code. I simplified it as much as possible without changing context. The situation is as follows:

I have two tables and want to check whether a person from Table1 is already present in Table2. If that's the case then just ignore it. Whereas if it's not, then I want to check another condition in Table1 (if `DateTime` field [Accepted] is not `NULL`) and if it is satisfied to proceed with processing that person's data.

However, even though I am able to get the `rst1![Name]` properly, when I get into the inner `if` I get the **424 runtime error: Object required**.

Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `If`-statement should read

```
If Not IsNull(rst1![Accepted]) Then
```

The `Is`-operator is used to compare object references, thus the error message.